# jQuery preventDefault() does not work in my MVC app

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get my javascript to add a row to a list of items using a partial view. In my main page, I define the list and button to add the row like this:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    @Html.Label("List Options", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    @if (Model.CustomFieldOptions != null)
    {
        <div id="editorRows">
            @foreach (var cfItem in Model.CustomFieldOptions)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_CustomFieldOptionEditorRow", cfItem);
            }
        </div>
    }
    @Html.ActionLink("Add another...", "_AddOptionEditorRow", null, new { id = "addItem" })
</div>
```

My javascript looks like this (UPDATED):

```
$("#addItem").click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#editorRows").append(html);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

My controller action is defined like this:

```
public PartialViewResult _AddOptionEditorRow()
{
    return PartialView("_CustomFieldOptionEditorRow", new CustomFieldOption());
}
```

This section of the page gets rendered like this:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <label class="control-label" for="List_Options">List Options</label>
    <div id="editorRows">   
        <div class="editorRow">
            ...
        </div>   
        <div class="editorRow">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="/customforms/_addoptioneditorrow" id="addItem">Add another...</a>
</div>
```

When I click the button I get navigated to:

> http://localhost:63595/customforms/_addoptioneditorrow

I would rather have it added to the div 'editorRows'.

Comment: Yes, the @Html.ActionLink gets the id 'addItem'.

Comment: As you are trying to override the click on the a tag, why not just define it as HTML rather than using the ActionLink helper, which is designed to help you automate routing URLs? Seems like you don't really want the URL here, except in the click, could you not write it into there instead? Would be safer for non-JavaScript users as you could construct the link to do nothing instead.

Comment: Also, have you checked that the click handler is firing at all (perhaps stick an alert() in there) - if there is an error elsewhere in your JavaScript, the binding may not have happened. Also, check your browsers error console, especially keep it open while you're clicking to see if you see a flash of error.

Comment: Why not just use a button - <button type="button" id="addItem">Add another...</button>` (and style it to look like a link if that's what you want)

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the fact that you reference `this.href` as the `$.ajax({url...});` I'm going to assume that `#addItem` is an anchor tag. By default, the anchor tag is used for navigation, so to use it for something other than that, you'll need to prevent the default action:

```
$("#addItem").click(function(evt) {    // <-- Add the event parameter "evt"
    evt.preventDefault();    // <-- Add this line
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, didn't work. Updated the post to reflect that.